# Referring to pictures and tables is only showing numbers

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, cleveref

When I use the `\ref{}` for referring to a picture or table, I do not get the wished result, which is for example (Fig 1.). Instead I get something like (1). Can one change that ? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Yes, load `cleveref` (after `hyperref` if you appen to  load it) and use `\cref` or `\Cref`  depending on the context.

Comment: Thanks. It is ok, but fig. or Fig is not hyperlinked. Is there a solution for that ? I tried hyperref to set as the last package, as I have learned it that way. But it did not change much.

Comment: or `\autoref` provided by `hyperref`. That one will produce `Figure <num>` and both will be clickable (and the `Figure` can be changed redefining `\figureautorefname`, iirc).

Comment: Great. Many thanks. It solved the problem.

Comment: You can always define commands like \eqref and \subref.